# How can I add in another description to my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

Okay guys, I am creating a chrome extension which allows my to use the omnibox feature in google chrome. So for example, When I type the word "face" and select tab, it allows be to use the chrome address bar as a searchbar for facebook.  I am now looking to add Twitter to the chrome extension and I am struggling to do this.
Below is my javascript file which works with facebook

```
function resetDefaultSuggestion() { 
    chrome.omnibox.setDefaultSuggestion({
        description: 'face: Search the Facebook API for %s'
        description: 'twitter: Search twitter API for %s'
    });
}

resetDefaultSuggestion();

function navigate(url) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: url});
    });
}

chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener(function(text) {  
  navigate("https://www.facebook.com/search/results/?q=" + text);
});
```

This is my manifest.JSON file below, any help at all would be appreciated:

```
{

    "name": "Facebook People Search", 
    "description": "Are you always facebook searching people? Install this plugin to make it even faster!",
    "omnibox": { "keyword" : "face" },
    "icons": {
    "16": "facebook.png"
    },
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
        "version": "1.0",
    "minimum_chrome_version": "9",
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: The omnibox already handles custom search engines, so I'm not sure to get the point of such an extension.

Comment: The reason is because I want to add github,linkedIn and Twitter as I find myself searching these 3 quite often.  I know it only saves about 5 seconds, but the omnibox feature is really nice and I wanted to use it when creating my chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, no can do.

Only one keyword per extension.

You'll need to have some kind of common prefix that's used for all queries to your extension.

For example, `s`, so you can do `s face` or `s f` for facebook and `s t` for twitter. See how [Chromium Search](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#chromium-search) does it for different search types.

Comment: Thanks Xan, I might just do 3 separate extensions, will let you know how I get on!

Comment: What's your use case? If that's just for personal use, you know Chrome can do it natively with Search Providers? At `chrome://settings/searchEngines`

Comment: Yes it is for personal use, it was partly because I had a small problem I wanted to solve, plus I wanted to get an opportunity to create my very own chrome extension is all.

Comment: The way I wanted to do it Xan, was so do you know the way if you type "you" into the addressbar, and then select tab, it allows you to do a youtube video search, it is a similar thing to this, except I wanted to append the text to do a people search in LinkedIn or Twitter, I currently have it working for facebook, but I just wish I could put all of them into 1 chrome extension.